# What exactly does struct nfs_unlinkdata do?

Tags: kernel

I been reading the source code of  `unlink()` but I am stuck on  `nfs_unlinkdata` and I can't find anything on it on the web.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: NFS usually refers to Network File System, so my hunch would be that nfsunlink is what you've read for `unlink()` plus the Network File System